# Django LogoutView does not emit user_logged_out signal

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication, django-login

I have an app that does not receive the `user_logged_out` signal that, in theory, should have been sent by `LogoutView`.

urls.py:

```py
...
   path('accounts/logout/',
      auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'),
         name='logout'),
...
```

myapp/signals.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_out
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(user_logged_out)
def extra_logout(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    # does some stuff
```

myapp/apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import myapp.signals
        return super().ready()
```

Note that `myapp` is loaded, everything else works. The django session is destroyed when calling `accounts/logout/`, but my receiver never gets the signal.

What am I doing wrong?

Django 2.2.3, Python 3.7.3 on mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried with your code and the missing part could be the `default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'` line in the **__init__.py** file in **myapp** folder. Please check with that and see if it works.